# How do I either make Ubuntu my default OS at start up without having to choose? Or, how do I delete my old operating system? Which option is better?

Tags: installation, default

I just installed Ubuntu. It did not prompt me to remove the old operating system when I installed Ubuntu. How do I either make Ubuntu my default OS at start up without having to choose? Or, how do I delete my old operating system? Which option is better?

Comment: What is the other OS you have on your machine? and what is the version of Ubuntu installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

If the other OS is working fine and you have a use for it, then better make a boot partition and run both the OS (NOTE:- system should be of good configuration so that it can run both the OS). If not, then best way is delete the first partition and just use Ubuntu and run (if required) other OS in virtual box.

Comment: What does a boot partition have to do with this? Are you thinking of installing GRUB to the MBR? That's independent of whether or not a separate boot partition exists.